# Optimal random bits complexity for universal hashing

Tags: hash-function, pseudorandomness

Let $Q_N:=\{0,1\}^N$ denote the $N$-dimensional Hamming cube. Let $a\in Q^N$ and $X\sim\mathrm{Unif}(Q^M)$ be input and random bits respectively, and function $f$ maps the the joint space to the $P$-dimensional cube $f:Q^{N+M}\to Q^P$. Defining hash function as $H(a):=f(a,X)$, what is the optimal $M$ if we require hash $H$ to be universal and uniform?
\begin{align}
&\Pr(H(a)=H(b))\le 2^{-P} &&\forall a,b\in Q^N, a\neq b\\
&\Pr(H(a)=c)=2^{-P} &&\forall c\in Q^P,a\in Q^N
\end{align}I'm interested in constructive answers, where $f$ can explicitly designed.

Comment: You need $H: \{0,1\}^N \to \{0,1\}^P$ where $P < N$, otherwise the answer is 0, since the identity function is universal.

Comment: If $N > P$, it cannot be the case that $\Pr[H(a) = H(b)] \leq 2^{-N}$. The best you can get, as Woelfel shows in "Efficient strongly universal and optimally universal hashing", is $(2^N - 2^P)/(2^{N+P} - 2^P)$. Did you maybe mean $\Pr[H(a) = H(b)] \leq 2^{-P}$?

Comment: yes sorry, corrected now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the best known bound is in Woelfel's "Efficient strongly universal and optimally universal hashing", Theorem 5, which presents a set with $M = N + \lfloor (N - P)/2 \rfloor - 1$, where $P$ is the number of bits in the codomain.

Comment: I thought of adding a constraint that $P(H(a)=h)=2^{-N}$ so that the identity cannot be a solution, but thought that your suggestion makes the problem more interesting, so changed it back

Comment: As you implied, this also applied when $P = N$, in which case the hash function is just multiplication by an odd number. Since this is a bijection, its collision probability is still $0$, which also implies it is uniform.